# Power automate workflow unable to process template language

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to get power automate to pull info from a google form fields, and populate an email depending on the answers to the field questions. I have tried doing a very basic flow, but every time I try running the flow, it keeps giving me an error. I have tried to delete and recreate the connects, like the documentation suggests but it isn't working. I was wondering if there is something I am missing. I have images of the flow as well as the error below. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: What does the Send Email action look like in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Send an email (V2)` action is outside the `For each` where the `Get response details` is, so it cannot access it. Try moving your `Send an email (V2)` action to within the `For each` after the `Get response details`.